# VLC Playlist with random selection from folders

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists, smart-playlist

I would like to make a simple playlist in VLC where the first file is loaded randomly from folder "A", then the second one randomly from folder "B", then loop from beginning and load different files from the folders. The problem is that the VLC expand the folders and plays all the files in them. How can I make such a playlist?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. [VLC Documentation](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Playlist/) on Playlists.

You could manually sort it (not random) or you would need to use two players. One playing folder A and one playing folder B.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a VLC issue. I could fix it following [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_R1NQbnZeQ).

Essentially go to:

1. Tools > Preferences
2. Show Settings > All (bottom left)
3. Playlist (on the left menu)
4. Enable "Play Randomly Forever" or "Subdirectory behavior > Expand" (on the right menu)
5. Restart VLC

Comment: For now step 4 is: Play files randomly forever

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve the exact result you specified, but I believe you can do a similar thing.

- First, open the playlist tab.
- Then, right-click empty space in the playlist and add preferred directories.
- After that, start playing any song you want and enable random playback order.

It works, but it has some shortcomings:

1. Folders should contain playable files only, or VLC may display an error (playback will continue anyway).
2. It will not explicitly play files from different folders one after another. Two files in sequence may be played from the same folder or may come from different. It's random.